# Why »Rettungsarbeit« is used only in the plural form?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, single-word-request, grammatical-number

The term *Rettungsarbeit*

is labeled as **Pluraletantum** in Duden Dictionary, i.e. it is used always in the plural form ***Rettungsarbeiten***.

I am seeking for justification from a semantic point of view for this plural usage.

---

In contrast thereto, *Rettungsaktion* is used just like other common countable nouns, i.e. both singular and plural numbers are current in actual use. The case of *Rettungsaktion* is perfectly fine to me. My difficulty is with *Rettungsarbeiten*.

Comment: I don't like the _Duden_ classification as _Pluralwort_ since this is proper too: _»Nach einem Erdbeben leisten Helfer [Rettungsarbeit](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Rettungsarbeit.html).«_ Compare _Aufbauarbeit_, _Bergungsarbeit_, _Büroarbeit_.

Comment: ,,you hurt my eyes''

Answer (score 4):

My personal opinion is:

A *Rettungsaktion* means everything necessary to save someone or something, as a whole.

A *Rettungsarbeit*, on the other hand, is one of the tasks necessary to fulfill the *Aktion*.

For a simple *Rettungsaktion*, such as getting your cat out of the tree, only a single *Arbeit* is necessary, therefore no one will speak of Rettungsarbeiten.

But more more complex tasks, such as after an earthquake, there are lots of different things to do, and these *different* things are summarized under the term *Rettungsarbeiten*.

It would also be possible to talk a single of these *Rettungsarbeiten* as especially important, but this is not done in practice since the these terms are typically used in the news, and they usually don't take their time to look at the details of what needs to be done, they just summarize. Therefore the singular is not needed.

Comment: *The singular is not needed*, +1 on this one. Die *Rettungsarbeit* is still countable as the base *Arbeit* is. It's just noone uses it, because it makes no sense in the context where it is used. Firemen would speak of the individual tasks they are doing, not about some undefined *Rettungsarbeit*.

Answer (score 0):

*Arbeiten* are all tasks necessary to fulfill a certain job. *Rettungsarbeiten* (like for example also *Reparaturarbeiten* or *Wartungsarbeiten*) are used in plural because rescuing most of the time consists of more than one task.